# Best way to display highlighted text by using DirectX 9

Tags: c++, fonts, sprite, directx-9

I'm trying to figure out the best way to display highlighted text by using DirectX 9 library.

Someone told me that one of the ways to do this is to create a white sprite from a file in memory and displaying that in a small rectangle and then drawing the text in black over the white sprite to give the highlighting effect.  Do you know how to do this?

On the other hand, t seems like overkill and I was wondering if any of you can tell me a better way to do this. I was hoping to just be able to DrawText() of some virtual key code that would display a white box and then I could put my real text in black over the top of it.

Any suggestions?